# Getting a private health insurance in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, health-insurance, health-system, nhs

We are moving from Switzerland to UK in a couple of months and I'm worried about adjusting to the nhs way of doing things. We would like to have:

- Direct access to a (specific) gynecologist for my wife
- Direct access to a (specific) pediatrician for my 1 month old baby

Is this possible through the nhs or do I always have to visit a GP and he decides whether we are referred? Would a private insurance cover this? I have found that they have very little information on their websites.

Comment: In my experience private healthcare policies require an initial referral from your gp.  Also the UK system is very GP focused, unless referred on for a specific reason, your child would normally see a GP, not a pediatrician

Comment: It's not only a matter of insurance but of the whole organisation of the healthcare system (and the NHS is not primarily an insurer, it also provides care). For example, in many countries women are not expected to visit a gynecologist once a year like they are in France or Germany (and, I surmise, in Switzerland?).

Comment: So, even if I have a private insure, I still have to go through the NHS GP to get a referral? We have lived in 3 countries in the past decade and in all of them the pediatrician (checkup, vaccines, and illnesses) and gynecologist (checkup) did not need a GP referral.

Comment: @electrique Typically, in a GP-based system, the GP does all the routine medical care for any patient, man, woman, or child. You would not need a referral for a child's checkup, vaccines, and minor illnesses or a woman's gynecological checkup because the GP would provide all that.

Comment: Thanks @PatriciaShanahan , although being used to yearly checkups by gynecologist and having a pediatrician keep track of the child's health, will make the adjustment hard. I was hoping that a private insurance would bridge the gap for these 2 specialists.

Comment: @electrique the GP will keep track of the child's health (and everyone else's); that's what a GP does.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, I would be interested to know what those three countries are. I knew things are different in France and Germany but I was under the impression that GP-based systems are more common in general.

Comment: @Relaxed in Switzerland you select a pediatrician at birth and he is solely responsible for the baby's health. In Belgium and in Cyprus, it's a similar approach to my knowledge. For the gynecologist I'm sure you can go without referral.

Comment: @electrique I am quite familiar with the model, it's just that it's not very common to my knowledge.

Comment: @Relaxed actually in Belgium you can go directly to any specialist without referral. The insurance covers it. In Switzerland, depending on the type of your insurance, you either go through GP (cheaper) or directly (more expensive). However, even in the cheapest ones, the gynecologist and pediatrician are exempted for the GP referral requirement. In Cyprus, for the nhs-equivalent system (state owned), you can book directly to a specialist. I was actually surprised to hear about the GP oriented UK system.

Comment: @electrique Yes, I heard you and like I said I am familiar with the model, what I meant is that, among the countries with universal healthcare, my impression is that there are more that are similar to the UK than to Belgium (and quite a few that are trying to move from the latter to the former model through financial incentives, which fits with your description of the Swiss system).

Comment: The issue with the gynecologist is a bit different. There are many countries where gynecologists are specialists who only deal with acute problems in a hospital setting, women are not expected to see one in a private practice on a regular basis or anything like that. Having lived in both France (beside the fact that insurance is state-run rather than private, the French system is very similar to the way you describe the Swiss system) and Germany, I completely understand where you are coming from but again that's not very common to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK health system is very GP based (and even on top of that nurse based). Most private insurance is "top up" insurance and adds features to the standard NHS care. In London, and some other cities, you can get insurance that covers more or less anything. That said, you need to weigh the costs and benefits carefully. You may be better off paying out of pocket for regular visits to the gynecologist and pediatrician than using insurance.

If you are going to be in the UK for a while, you may want to work on getting used to the way they do things. It is easier said than done, but in the long run probably worth it.